# Why this map is not a cover map?

Tags: general-topology, covering-spaces

My teacher says that a trivial example of a non cover map is $f:[-1,1]\rightarrow[0,1]$ defined as
$$ f(x)=|x|$$

$f$ is surjective and continuous. Also, for every $x\in[0,1]$ we can find a neighborhood $U$ such that $p^{-1}(U)$ can be written as two disjoints open sets of $[-1,1]$ (One containing the negative interval and the other containing the positive ones). If we restrict $p$ to one of these intervals we have a continuous bijection with continuous inverse hence a homeomorphism. Consequently, $f$ is a cover map.

To be more precise, if $0<x<1$, $\varepsilon>0$ and $U=(x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)$ then $$p^{-1}(U)=(-x-\varepsilon,-x+\varepsilon)\cup(x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)=V_1\cup V_2$$ Then $\left. p\right|_{V_1}=-Id_{V_1}$ and $\left. p\right|_{V_2}=Id_{V_2}$

Comment: For $x=0$, what is an example of a neighborhood $U$ such that $p^{-1}(U)$ can be written as two disjoint neighborhoods of $[-1,1]$? The inverse will contain $0$ which is neither positive nor negative.

Comment: @SlipEternal We can take $U=(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)$ and $p^{-1}(U)=(-\varepsilon,0)\cup [0,\varepsilon)$

Comment: What do you mean by “neighborhoods of $[−1,1]$”?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos sorry, I wanted to write "open sets of" as the definition of evenly covered (See [here](https://www.geneseo.edu/~johannes/covering.pdf) the definition)

Comment: @Cofinite $[0,\epsilon)$ is a half-open interval, not an open subset of $U$. You split it into an open set and a set that is neither open nor closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Also, for every $x\in[0,1]$ we can find a neighborhood $U$ such that $p^{-1}(U)$ can be written as two disjoints open sets of $[-1,1]$ (One containing the negative interval and the other containing the positive ones). If we restrict $p$ to one of these intervals we have a continuous bijection with continuous inverse hence a homeomorphism.

That is not true for $x=0$. If $U\subseteq [0,1]$ is an open neighbourhood of $0$, then $p^{-1}(U)$ is an open neighbourhood of $0$ in $[-1,1]$. But any open neighbourhood of $0$ in $[-1,1]$ contains some interval $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$ on which $p$ is not injective. And so $p$ cannot be a homeomorphism on at least one component of $p^{-1}(U)$.

> To be more precise, if $0<x<1$ (...)

Yes, that reasoning is fine, **only when** $x>0$. In particular $p$ is a covering map as a map $[-1,1]\backslash\{0\}\to (0,1]$. But in your case note that when $x=0$, then we already have a problem at $U=(x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon)$, which isn't a subset of $[0,1]$. If we take $U=[0,\epsilon)$, which is a valid open neighbourhood of $0$ in $[0,1]$, then $p^{-1}(U)=(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$ which does not decompose into negative and positive open pieces, and $p$ is not injective on it.